# Impossibility to open a file for modification in ESP32

Tags: sd-card, esp32, sd

Consider the following code:

```
#include "SD.h"
#include "Fs.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  if (!SD.begin(5)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    // don't do anything more:
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");

  File file = SD.open("/test.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  file.write((const uint8_t*)"is a test", 10);
  file.close();

  file = SD.open("/test.txt", FILE_WRITE); <-- Tested with APPEND too
  file.seek(0);
  file.write((const uint8_t*)"this", 4);
  file.close();

  file = SD.open("/test.txt", FILE_READ);

  while (file.available()) {
    Serial.write(file.read());
  }
  file.close();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

If I open the file with FILE_WRITE the contents of the file are zeroed and I get as output:

> "this"

And if I open the file in mode FILE_APPEND then seek() does not work and I get as output:

> "is a testthis"

How to modify this program so I get any of both?

> "thisis a test" [insert] (or) "thistest" [overwrite]

Using an ESP32 here as I think the File or the SD objects are different than the Arduino ones.

Comment: `"FILE_WRITE"` should be just `FILE_WRITE`.  It's a macro that equates to `"w"`

Comment: Good catch but that was a paste error, the code was fine. I've fixed the code here but the problem remains.

Comment: The ESP32 implementation is somewhat convoluted. It goes through multiple layers of compatibility wrappers to use the underlying SDK calls. If write always truncates, and append never seeks, then there is something wrong or lacking in those compatibility layers. You should open an issue on Github, https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues

Comment: Thanks, issue opened: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/4028